# Easy way to prevent rails console displaying numbers (decimal, float, integers) in scientific notation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-console

Is there some default configuration that can be altered to prevent scientific notation in the rails console **without** having to configure it on a per-column basis? (i.e. I'd like to just run some config line once somewhere and have it apply across all tables/columns for that app, if possible).

#### Example

Here is an example where scientific notation sort of gets in the way

```
Product.first

cost: 0.99999998999923e12,
currency: "USD",
charge: 0.55e1,
charge_currency: "AUD",
price: 0.5e2,
price_currency: "AUD"
```

I'd prefer to see 999999989999.23 instead of 0.99999998999923e12, 5.5 instead of 0.55e1, 50 instead of 0.5e2. I find regular numbers much more natural and easy to read.

#### What I know so far

There are a couple of ideas in the answers to [*Rails console shows value in scientific notation*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61570678/5783745), but both are on a per column/attribute basis.

#### Note

I'd be happy to install a gem (I already use pry if that helps), and basically want a convenient way of avoiding scientific notation when displaying integers/floats/decimals but without having to write code specific to the model/columns/types.

Comment: Use the number helpers provided by [ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html) or the [money gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money). What you're otherwise proposing would mean that you would have to monkeypatch `Numeric#to_s` and it's not a good idea - the core data class should not be concerned with how you want to present numbers.

Comment: As an alternative to the helpers you can use the [Decorator pattern](https://github.com/drapergem/draper).

Comment: Thanks @max, I appreciate the suggestions. I fear the ActionView helpers require implementation on a per column (or even per value) basis? Although it's from far outside the ruby ecosystem, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25947542/5783745) is a great example of what I really hope I can find. Basically the R programming language also defaults to displaying in scientific notation, but with one tiny command - `options(scipen=999)` - it completely removes all scientific notation from the R console, which is hugely relieving. I hope I can find (or even make) something just as easy in rails.

Comment: The helpers are completly functional - you input a number and a format and it gives you back a formatted string. And yes you would have to implement it as an extra layer.

Comment: @max But wouldn't I have to use those formatters on a per value/column basis? What if the database is 1000 tables? Note the R example requires just one line of code to completely relieve the entire console session from any scientific notation. I don't think the same can be achieved with ActionView helpers, at least nowhere near as tersely?

Comment: The rest of your question has nothing to do with Rails really. Its fully possible to monkeypatch how Ruby displays numbers via `to_s` and `inspect` but doing so may unleash a maelstrom of bugs. Is it really worth the effort?

Comment: @max makes sense. I guess that rules out monkeypatching, as any high risk of bugs would be undesirable.